# Vb.net Random Number generator repeats same numbers

Tags: vb.net, random

What should i add to random number generator coding, so numbers wont repeat themselves more times in a row?

My random number generator looks like this:

```
Dim rn As New Random
TextBox1.Text = rn.Next(1, 4)
If TextBox1.Text = 1 Then
    Form4.Show()
    Form4.Timer1.Start()
End If

If TextBox1.Text = 2 Then
    Form7.Show()
    Form7.Timer1.Start()
End If

If TextBox1.Text = 3 Then
   Form8.Show()
   Form8.Timer1.Start()
End If
```

Comment: You mean you don't want sometthing like `1 2 2 / 3 1 1 / 2 3 3` and something like `1 3 2 / 2 1 3 / 3 1 2` instead?

Comment: Yes, now its 1 2 2 / 3 1 1 / 2 3 3... i want 1 3 2 / 2 1 3 / 3 1 2...

Comment: random numbers do repeat especially with such a small range. you could store the last number as a var and keep getting new randoms until it doesnt match the previous one.

Comment: You could just arrange the numbers 1,2,3 in a random order.

Comment: I cant arrange them in random order, because soon there will me many more questions. And im making quiz so i needs to be every time different

Comment: Move the Random outside of the Sub so that there is not a possibility of it being seeded with the same number.  As has been noted with this small range of numbers you can(should)  expect repeats.  Also, turn Option Strict On and fix the errors.  FWIW I wouldn't use the default instances of the Forms.

Answer (score 1):

Given N (at present N = 3 but it could be something else, as you say), try to construct a random permutation of 1, ..., N, then open the text boxes in the order that is generated. Note that that means you're generating N numbers at a time and using them all up, then generating N more. Search for "random permutation" to find an algorithm.

Comment: This is the way to go. To make it easy, you can easily swap two random elements n / 2 times.

Comment: This is also called "Fisher-Yates" or "Knuth" shuffle.  See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Move your Random instance, "rn", out to Class (Form) level so it only gets created ONCE for the Form, and the same instance gets used over and over:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private rn As New Random

    Private Sub SomeMethod()
        TextBox1.Text = rn.Next(1, 4)
        If TextBox1.Text = 1 Then
            Form4.Show()
            Form4.Timer1.Start()
        End If

        If TextBox1.Text = 2 Then
            Form7.Show()
            Form7.Timer1.Start()
        End If

        If TextBox1.Text = 3 Then
            Form8.Show()
            Form8.Timer1.Start()
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: He doesn't want any numbers repeated

Comment: Fixed it! The problem was that i had two         Dim rn As New Random , now it works fine.  Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

To get a random integer value between 1 and N (inclusive) you can use the following.

```
CInt(Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * n))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want each number only used once, you need to do something like this:

```
Const FirstNumber As Integer = 1
Const LastNumber As Integer = 5

' Fill the list with numbers
Dim numberList as New List(Of Integer)
For i As Integer = FirstNumber To LastNumber Step 1
    numberList.Add(i)
Next i

Dim rand as New Random()
While numberList.Count > 0
    ' draw a random number from the list
    Dim randomIndex As Integer = rand.Next(0, numberList.Count - 1)
    Dim randomNumber As Integer = numberList(randomIndex)

    ' Do stuff with the number here        
    TextBox1.Text = randomNumber

    ' remove the number from the list so it can't be used again
    numberList.RemoveAt(randomIndex)
End While
```

Comment: It is not clear from the OP if this is like a deck of cards being dealt or the roll of a die.